# data frame with commas as decimal separator

Tags: r, csv

I have data frame as csv file, numbers are separated with commas as decimal separators, I managed to import and read it in R using `read.csv2`. But now numbers are seen as `characters`.

What I want to do is to replace commas with dots and have a `numeric` value.

My df looks like this:

```
var1 <- c("50,0", "72,0", "960,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
var2 <- c("40,0", "742,0", "9460,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
var3<- c("40,0", "72,0", "90,0", "1,30", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
df <- data.frame(cbind(var1, var2, var3))
```

However in this case numbers are seen as factors and not as characters

Comment: `as.numeric(sub(',', '.', your_var, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but: `as.numeric(gsub(",",".",var))`?  A reproducible example would be very useful.

Comment: @ Sotos, can my variable be a subset of my data frame or do Ì need to replace for each column

Comment: you can apply, for example `df[c(1, 4, 5)] <- lapply(df[c(1, 4, 5)], function(i) as.numeric(sub(',', '.', i, fixed = TRUE)))` will apply the `sub` to columns 1, 4 and 5. For any further help please post a reproducible example

Comment: @Sotos worked pretty well!

Comment: Also [as.numeric with comma decimal separators?](/q/15236440/15497888) if wanting to post process rather than directly from CSV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read in the .csv file, you can specify the `sep` and `dec` parameters based on the file-type:

```
# assuming file uses ; for separating columns and , for decimal point
# Using base functions 
read.csv(filename, sep = ";", dec = ",")

# Using data.table
library(data.table)
fread(filename, sep = ";", dec = ",")
```

You should attempt to address the source of the issue first, regular expressions and other work-arounds should be used only if that fails to get the desired result.